# Explanation of Sportsmanship badge

Tags: support, badges

What exactly is "Up voted 100 competing answers"? Does it mean to upvote an answer which competes with one's own or to upvote at least two answers to the same question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The former: upvoting answers by other users on questions you've answered yourself.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @WilliWong: Do Meta and normal answers add up?

Comment: @draks: meta and the main sites have separate sets of badges, and are counted as if they are two different sites. So the answer to your question is: no.

Comment: @WillieWong, Is there a "time range" or "time limit" taken into account of both actions?

Comment: @Pacerier: I guess not. Usually when there is some sort of time-limit then they would say it in the description. And the [official description does not say anything](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/sportsmanship) to that effect.